# Mono for Droid: missing __ANDROID__ symbol

Tags: android, compilation, mono, conditional-statements, symbols

In this interesting webinar:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WkNbRUqnSSc

the speaker talks about the `__ANDROID__` symbol (*and others symbols more specific to each OS version*) that could help a developer write a cleaner cross-platform code.

I've created a project with MonoDevelop 2.8 (under MacOS X) and the symbol seems not to be defined inside the project.

Investigating this issue, I've noticed that defining symbols (*using project properties panel*) not always work in MonoDevelop and they often create weird things with color coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a glitch in the current MonoDevelop environment. __ANDROID__ is defined in low-level build process and not csproj. So code will compile OK, but the editor will be very confused.

I've created a [bug/enhancement request](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7397) with Xamarin as this can trip up newbs (it did me!).

This [thread](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Conditional-Compilation-Symbols-td5711427.html) in the monodroid mailing list has more information.

Since I have unique csproj files for each platform -- even for shared code -- I just create my own symbol to get around this. In MonoDevelop: project properties, Build->Compiler, Define Symbols.